# Joseki mysql sparql

Tags: mysql, rdf, sparql, jena

I configured the joseki with mysql and also modified the joseki-config-sdb.ttl.
When I pass the select query I am getting the error like 
**The server encountered an internal error (com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.core.Quad.isDefaultGraphIRI()Z) 
that prevented it from fulfilling this request.**

Please find the stack trace in the following 
url http://pastie.org/1975277 
Version of the build are 
Joseki-3.4.4,sdb-1.3.4 and java 1.6 and the query is select * where {?s ?p ?o}

Please Let me know what I am missing here.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll need to provide more information. Is there a stacktrace for the error? Which Java, Jena and Joseki versions are you using? What's your configuration? What's the query? It may take some dialogue to get to the root cause, in which case posting the question to the jena-users support list at Apache might be a more effective way to get this problem sorted.

Comment: Hi thanks,Please find the stack trace in the following url http://pastie.org/1975277 Joseki-3.4.4,sdb-1.3.4 and java 1.6 and the query is select * where {?s ?p ?o}

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me as though you have incompatible versions of the `.jar` files. The exception you get is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.core.Quad.isDefaultGraphIRI
```

[`NoSuchMethodError`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html) is thrown when the JVM has resolved the class name to a class object, but that class does not have the method requested. Code won't compile with this problem, so the fact that you're encountering it in compiled code means that you have mixed-up versions of the classes.

You need to ensure that the `lib` directory of your tomcat application has *only* Jena `.jar` files from the version of Joseki you are using. No older or newer versions, or duplicates. I suggest deleting everything in `lib`, then copying in just one set of Jena jars from your Joseki installation, and then any other `.jar` files your app needs.

Comment: I did not  mixed up any jar files,only mysql connector is downloaded & placed in lib folder.Joseki is  deployed in tomcat using war file.I will try to deploy once again.                                          Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use arq-2.8.7.  arq-2.8.8 do not have the missing method in the Quad class.